# How to show Box shadow in print?

Tags: css, printing

Is it possible to show the box shadow in a print?

I´m using box shadow instead of borders in my layout.
Now i like to print it, but the box shadow won´t show up in the print.

How can i solve this?

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black inset !important;
```

This is what i´m trying to print:
http://jsfiddle.net/Tx4Uv/177/

**EDIT**

I´ve tried this without any success:

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
-webkit-filter:opacity(1);
```

Comment: i believe you need to turn it on in printer configuration. where you allow or not to print backgrounds. Only the user has access to this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is only supported in chrome with:

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
```

[developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust)

Try create an css with media type print:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

[CSS Design: Going to Print](https://alistapart.com/article/goingtoprint)

Hope it helped you.

Answer (score -5):

Hope this code will help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: yellow;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px grey;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>This is a div element with a box-shadow</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to print this and you will see it´s not working!